# Val not recognised/used in Scala application

Tags: scala, mapping

Provided the following text file:

```
Alabama (9),Democratic:849624,Republican:1441170,Libertarian:25176,Others:7312
Alaska (3),Democratic:153778,Republican:189951,Libertarian:8897,Others:6904
Arizona (11),Democratic:1672143,Republican:1661686,Libertarian:51465,Green:1557,Others:475
```

Looking to create a scala application - mapped the data from a text file to then be filtered via the app. Unsure why parties is not being used in the following block of code:

```
  def readFile(filename: String): Map[(String, Int), Map[String, Int]] = {
val mapBuffer: Map[(String, Int), Map[String, Int]] = Map()
try {
  for (line <- Source.fromFile(filename).getLines()) {
    val strings = line.split("\n").toList
    val  parties = strings.map { x =>
      val entries = x.split(",").toList
      val stateAndCode = entries.head
      val state = stateAndCode.takeWhile(_ != '(').trim
      val code = stateAndCode.dropWhile(_ != '(').takeWhile(_ != ')').toInt
      val votes = entries.tail.map { x =>
        val Array(party, number) = x.split(":")
        (party.trim, number.toInt)
      }
      ((state, code), votes.toMap)}.groupBy(_._1).view.mapValues(_.head).toMap
  }
}
catch {
  case ex: Exception => println("Sorry, an exception happened.")
}
mapBuffer
}
```

Would appreciate any feedback on how to improve this block. The first use of the map is to return all information from the map basically - this is the instruction given:

**Get all the state/district values and display suitably formatted.**

The attempted implementation of this is as follows:

def stateVotes = parties.keySet.map{case (party, code) => s"Party(district):", "\n", "\n" )

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would appreciate any feedback on how to improve this block.

My suggestion: start over.

```
val dataRE = "([^(]+) \\((\\d+)\\),(.+)".r
val pVotes = "([^:]+):(\\d+)".r

case class State(name    : String
                ,code    : Int
                ,parties : Array[(String,Int)])

val states: List[State] =
  util.Using(io.Source.fromFile("data.txt"))(_.getLines().toList)
      .get  //will throw if read file fails
      .collect{case dataRE(name,code,votes) =>
        State(name.trim
             ,code.toInt
             ,votes.split(",")
                   .collect{case pVotes(p,v) => (p,v.toInt)}
             )
      }
```

After all the data has been collected into a `List` of `State` instances then you just need a few tools to manipulate and format lists and strings.

Say, for example, you want to print out all the data in a consistent and well organized fashion.

```
states.sortBy(_.name)     //alphabetical
      .foreach{ st =>
        println(st.name)  //state name
        st.parties
          .sortBy(-_._2)  //votes in decreasing order
          .map{case (p,v) => f"\t$p%-12s:$v%9d"}
          .foreach(println)
      }
```

result:

```
Alabama
    Republican  :  1441170
    Democratic  :   849624
    Libertarian :    25176
    Others      :     7312
Alaska
    Republican  :   189951
    Democratic  :   153778
    Libertarian :     8897
    Others      :     6904
Arizona
    Democratic  :  1672143
    Republican  :  1661686
    Libertarian :    51465
    Green       :     1557
    Others      :      475
```

Or maybe you'd like to see vote totals for each state.

```
states.map(st => (st.name, st.parties.map(_._2).sum))
      .sortBy(-_._2)  //votes in decreasing order
      .map{case (state,total) => f"$state%-9s:$total%8d"}
      .foreach(println)
```

result:

```
Arizona  : 3387326
Alabama  : 2323282
Alaska   :  359530
```

You get the idea.

Comment: is there a way of making the list of state instances a map? like Map[String, Int, List[(String, Int)] but have the data behave in the same way? I am trying to get this triggered via an actionMap/handler but can't quite crack it.

Comment: would I be able to email you a more in-depth explanation of my issue with screenshots etc? Or would you prefer I wrote out a new stackoverflow Q and tagged you? @jwvh

Comment: You certainly _can_ use a `Map` but a `Map` requires 2 types: the key type and the value type. How would you manage the 3 types: `String`, `Int`, and `List`? You might have 2 maps, a `String`->`Int` map as well as a `String`->`List` map. Sounds cumbersome but workable. Post a fresh SO question. No need to tag me. I'll see it.

Comment: Thanks, I will post the new question in the morning.

Comment: Hi I have posted the new question with a lot more detail of what I'm trying to achieve